# Unexpected reserved word error using Jest

Tags: jasmine, browserify, jestjs

I'm trying to add Jest tests to my project (using React, Browserify and Babel), but I'm getting an error while doing the most basic thing:

With this structure:

```
|- /app
  |- /scripts    
    |- /models
      |- Vendor.js
      |- /__tests__
         |- Vendor-test.js
```

And this code:

**Vendor.js:**

```
class Vendor {
  constructor(json) {
   this.id = json.vendor_id;
  }
}

module.exports = Vendor;
```

**Vendor-test:**

```
jest.dontMock('../Vendor.js');

describe('Vendor', function() {
 it('Vendor creation', function() {
     var Vendor = require('../Vendor');
     var vendor = new Vendor({vendor_id:1});
     expect(vendor.id).toBe(1);
   });
 });
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
app/scripts/models/Vendor.js: Unexpected reserved word
        at Contextify.sandbox.run (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:12:24)
        at JSDomEnvironment.runSourceText (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/src/JSDomEnvironment.js:108:22)
        at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:345:23)
        at Loader._execModule (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:250:9)
        at Loader.requireModule (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:916:12)
        at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:937:17)
        at Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/app/scripts/models/__tests__/Vendor-test.js:5:18)
        at jasmine.Block.execute (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:1065:17)
        at jasmine.Queue.next_ (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2098:31)
        at null._onTimeout (/Users/jasalguero/work/projects/monoqi/b2b-frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2088:18)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

Actually the error happens as soon as I require a module. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error when parsing **Vendor.js** as **ES5**, it's seems it is not being transpiled with babeljs in your jasmine+jest tests

See https://babeljs.io/docs/using-babel/#jest for instructions on using jest with babeljs

Comment: that was it! I was just following the jest instructions assuming that it was made for using with React and they would handle the modules automagically...

Answer (score 4):

I kept getting this error even after installing babel-jest.

The solution was to create a `.babelrc` file in the root directory. Inside it you define the presets you need, for example like this:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Also, there is a `node_modules/jest-cli/.haste-cache` directory which might lead to too much caching. Consider disabling it with the [preprocessCachingDisabled option](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html).